# What does "use this SASS mixin" mean in the context of Material Design Components?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins, gwt-material-design

I am using the [Material Design Components for Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) library. I have a [tab component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-tab-indicator) that I'd like to change the `underline-color` of.

The instructions say

> To customize the tab indicator, use the following mixins.

Then it gives a table. For underline color, it says

> underline-color($color) Customizes the color of the underline.

So, I try in my `scss` file, the following:

```
  .mdc-tab-indicator {
      underline-color(red);
  }
```

I compile my sass (using `dart-sass`) and get the following error

```
Error: expected "{".
```

It says this is a "Sass Mixin." So, I look at the [SASS documentation on mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin). I see nothing that follows the syntax `mixin-name($variable)`. Everything in there looks like

```
@mixin reset-list {
  margin: 0;
}
```

with curly braces, not parentheses. But, the error said it was expecting a curly brace, and also apparently the `@` symbol is required. So, I try:

```
  .mdc-tab-indicator {
      @underline-color(red);
  }
```

This doesn't throw an error, but doesn't cause the underline color to change. I try to follow the syntax of the sass docs:

```
  .mdc-tab-indicator {
      @underline-color(red){};
  }
```

No error, but no color change. I try to match the syntax better:

```
  .mdc-tab-indicator {
      @mixin underline-color(red){};
  }
```

This throws

```
Error: expected ")".
```

I try

```
  .mdc-tab-indicator {
      @mixin underline-color(red);
  }
```

Same error.

I don't understand what the material components documentation is instructing. What does it mean when it says "To customize the tab indicator, use the following mixins." ? How can I change the underline color of the Material Design Component tab indicator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixins are defined using the @mixin at-rule, which is written @mixin  { ... } or @mixin name() { ... }. A mixin’s name can be any Sass identifier, and it can contain any statement other than top-level statements. They can be used to encapsulate styles that can be dropped into a single style rule; they can contain style rules of their own that can be nested in other rules or included at the top level of the stylesheet; or they can just serve to modify variables.

Mixins are included into the current context using the @include at-rule, which is written @include  or @include (), with the name of the mixin being included.

So, to include your specific mixin use:

```
.mdc-tab-indicator {
      @include underline-color(red);
  }
```

See more at https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin