# Material Design tab-Indicator Mixin Undefined

Tags: material-design, material-components, mdc-components, material-components-web

I've been trying out material design for the first time and am struggling to get mixins for the tab-indicator to work. I'm new to this framework and using sass so I'm sure I'm missing something.

`App.scss` looks like this:

```css
@use "@material/theme" with (
    $primary: #33302d,
    $secondary: #d6c266,
    $on-primary: #d6d6d6,
    $on-secondary: #000000,
);

@use '@material/button/mdc-button';
@use '@material/button';
@use "@material/icon-button";
@use "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";
@use "@material/tab-bar/mdc-tab-bar";
@use "@material/tab-scroller/mdc-tab-scroller";
@use "@material/tab-indicator/mdc-tab-indicator";
@use "@material/tab/mdc-tab";

@include icon-button.core-styles;

body {
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
};

.mdc-tab-indicator {
    @include underline-color(orange);
};
```

And when I compile the file, I keep getting the error:

```css
ERROR in ./app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
25 │     @include underline-color(orange);
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  app.scss 25:5  root stylesheet
```

I'm not sure how to trouble-shoot this, as all the documentation I've found and other solutions (e.g. [What does "use this SASS mixin" mean in the context of Material Design Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404999/what-does-use-this-sass-mixin-mean-in-the-context-of-material-design-component)) indicate this should work.

What's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems here:

1. `@use` adds namespace to imported members, see [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) docs. So you should prefix mixin with the namespace.
2. It is **not** recommended practice to name your class the same way as existing MDC class - `.mdc-tab-indicator`. Create new name and add it to your tab indicator html element.
3. MDC packages have two ways of including them into your SASS-file:

   ```scss
   // This will add all mdc-tab-indicator classes to your CSS
   @use "@material/tab-indicator/mdc-tab-indicator";

   // This will include mixins and variables, but will not add classes to CSS.
   // It is useful if your SASS is broken down into multiple smaller SASS files
   // and you don't want duplicate mdc-tab-indicator CSS each time you add @use.
   @use "@material/tab-indicator";
   ```

   My guess is that you need both, since you need base mdc-tab-indicator CSS classes. Plus you want to use mixins to create customized tab indicator.

So the final result looks like this:

```scss
@use "@material/tab-indicator";
@use "@material/tab-indicator/mdc-tab-indicator";

.my-tab-indicator {
    @include tab-indicator.underline-color(orange);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, it's helped me understand more about SASS. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error message using this with the namespace.

Comment: @AnKo I took another look at the problem and updated the answer with additional details. Notice I changed class name and namespace. Just in case, here is working example. It doesn't render tab-indicator, but it compiles - https://codesandbox.io/s/tab-indicator-test-ntfo8?file=/src/app.scss